# How to bulk-delete nodes with particular key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to delete all nodes with particular user key in any levels deeper while user profile deletion in Firebase. So I wonder is it possible to do that by some elegant way? Thanks.

Comment: What is your database structure?  What code have you already tried to do this (even if it may not be elegant, as you say)?

Comment: There is no way to pass query conditions into the Firebase Database and have it delete those items. You'll need to run the query to retrieve the keys/paths of the matching items and then delete those. If the solutions in the question I linked don't work for you, update your question with what you've tried so we can have a look.

Comment: @DougStevenson In DB I have many nodes with user key in various levels, so I need go over all DB to find that keys